# Clean html code with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I "clean away" all but the word dog from the html code below using Javascript
and perhaps regex? The id will vary.

```
<div class="tag" id="11">dog</div>
```

Comment: You want to extract the text present within div?

Comment: You don't want to use regexp. Instead you want to parse HTML using DOM routines and then manipulate the DOM tree. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although its very bad idea to parse html via js , but if you want then try this

```
<.*>(.*)<\/.*>
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/p7Qk02PmhU)

Answer (score 2):

ids should **not** begin with a digit.

```
<div class="tag" id="d11">dog</div>

var who= document.getElementById('d11');
alert(who.textContent || who.innerText || '');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be `class=tag`, then a bit of jquery can help with this:

```
$('.tag').html()
```

If it's in a string already

```
var s = '<div class="tag" id="11">dog</div>';
$(s,'.tag').html()
```

Comment: `$(s,'.tag')` should just be `$(s)`.